# PHP connecting to wrong MySQL hostname?

Tags: dns, php, mysql, vps, hosting

I just recently got a VPS server from a large hosting provider. I have a site that I've hosted a few other places so I know my code works

This provider has you create a MySQL hostname which you use to connect to mysql. I set mine up as **mysql.[domainname].com**. You cannot connect through localhost

For example, lets say my domain is **testdomain.test**

I'd create my connection using (In PHP)

```
new mysqli(“mysql.testdomain.test”, “user”, $password, $dbname)
```

However, when I run/load my PHP scripts I get an error

```
Access denied for user ‘user’@’unrelateddomain.com’ (using password: YES)
```

I've never even heard of this **unrelateddomain.com** and I have no idea where it came from. (unrelateddomain.com is a placeholder, but the site it's actually trying to connect to is a real site)

If I SSH into the server, I can connect using

```
mysql -h mysql.testdomain.test -u user -p
```

I can also connect through a PHPMyAdmin using mysql.testdomain.com

After my research my best guess is it has to do with a DNS reverse lookup MySQL might make. But I can't find anyone with similar issues.

Thank you, I really do appreciate it

Edit: 2/9/2019

I bought a new domain, refreshed/redone absolutely everything I could, and made a new site specifically to test this, and the error still persists.

Comment: Can you connect via an IP address in either php or the command line to mysql.testdomain.test? Secondly, what happens when you do a 'dig' command (nslookup in Windows) for either mysql.testdomain.test or unrelateddomain.com?

Comment: Thank you for the comment @pkSML, I cannot connect via IP because it's a VPS and I many servers share the same IP (I believe) I have tried connecting via IP and it has not worked. My nslookup shows a different IP than the VPS server, but that's only because they're on different servers. I get the same results regardless of the computer I run it on. I also contacted my Hosting Provider and they refreshed/cleaned their DNS cache

Comment: It's a long shot, but if they're a large hosting provider, they should have some documentation about how to successfully connect to their MySQL servers. But if you're running a VPS, wouldn't MySQL be running on *your own* server, available at localhost / 127.0.0.1? Edit: re-read your original post...

Comment: Is there a reason you can't host MySQL on your own VPS? My next guess would be thinking that the DNS A record for mysql.yourdomain.com has a CNAME record pointing to unrelateddomain.com.

Comment: @pkSML That's just the way they do it. Their SQL server is completely unrelated. I have read their documentation and it's exactly the way i'm connecting. viewdns.info tells me there are 3 domains on my VPS server -- but there are no CNAME records.

Comment: I don't know if the moderators frown on it, but it would seem helpful to know who your provider is. Also: Do you get the IP address returned for nslookup/dig mysql.testdomain.test on your VPS vs. your home computer?

Comment: @pkSML yeah I wasn't sure if the mods frown on it, but i'm using dreamhost. I do get the same nslookup on the VPS server and my home computer. The IP address of the VPS and SQL server are not the same. viewdns.info tells me one of the 3 domains on my VPS server IS the unrelated domain; but interestingly, the mysql host name, only has one other domain on its server, and its NOT the unrelated domain.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. And by CNAME records, I mean logging into your domain registrar and checking DNS records for your domain, especially the mysql.yourdomain.com A record. If Dreamhost is both your registrar and server provider, it might be a little more complex. In any regard, the only people that could probably help you are people who've had the same problem and fixed it or the Dreamhost people. Honestly, I think it's a misconfiguration on Dreamhost's part. They need to make a user on the MySQL server for you. Note: Your username to log in to MySQL may need to include your domain name.

Comment: @pkSML They have their CNAME record point to autoconfig.dreamhost.com. Thanks for the help. I've already contacted their support team. I guess I'll submit a different ticket. The strangest part is I can connect everywhere, except through PHP

Comment: Yes, that it very weird indeed! http://php.net/manual/en/function.gethostbyname.php will show you what IPv4 address PHP is using to connect BTW.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted their support and they basically told me not their problem. Nothing to do with them.

I tried searching everything to no avail. Gave up for a few weeks. Told the guy i'm doing this for 'Sorry; It's Dreamhosts fault. Nothing I can do'

Decided to take another look at it today, and it just started working. I of course have not touched a thing, nor has anyone else.

Any poor soul experiencing this:

**Contact your provider; It's almost certainly an issue on there end. Wait a few days for proper propagation.**

The issue had to have been on their end and was fixed after a blazing fast 4 weeks. I of course have no idea on specifics

Comment: While I am glad that you found a solution, and praise you for sharing it with others, I advise you not to [cross post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54499414/php-mysql-connecting-to-wrong-and-unrelated-domain). That is strongly frowned upon and will result in both posts being put on hold & possibly deleted.